# Mapbox: how to adjust the amount of dashes in a line-dasharray animation based on a variable?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

We are at the final phase of a product development project for a client using Mapbox!
the final thing we need to implement is actually based on this example they provided https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-ant-path/

The dasharray is actually an array of predefined dashes, but we want to have "control"  over the amount of dashes and gaps...
a user has the option to select low, medium and high and based on that value, the amount of dashes and gaps increases or decreases.
But I can't find a good way to achieve this.. it's probably something easy, but I don't know how

best guess is to rebuild the array for the dashsequence again?
And how would you go about to slow down the animation?

any help would be much appreciated!

thanks!

Comment: Do you have any (attempt) code in place to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply alter (change dynamically) the dasharray definition based on some user preference:

For example: change the second value in the of the items in the array (no idea what this "does" , find out yourself )

```
changeDashArray(userDefinedSetting) {    

dashArraySequence = [
      [0, userDefinedSetting, 3],
      [0.5, userDefinedSetting, 2.5],
      [1, userDefinedSetting, 2],
      [1.5, userDefinedSetting, 1.5],
      [2, userDefinedSetting, 1],
      [2.5, userDefinedSetting, 0.5],
      ...
    ];

animateDashArray();

}
```

As the Mapbox example states:

> Update line-dasharray using the next value in dashArraySequence. The
> divisor in the expression `timestamp / 50` controls the animation
> speed.

So by changing this expression:

```
const newStep = parseInt((timestamp / 50) % dashArraySequence.length);
```

the speed of the animation can be controlled.